# In inheritance, what if subclass does not adhere to all super class behavior?

Tags: java, oop, inheritance

Like there is Mammal class have behavior of walking which all subclasses should adhere to.

But there are few mammals like Dolphin and Bat which does not have this behavior possessed.

How can we implement this?

As per me, all subclasses should adhere to all behavior related to super class.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: You should never user cars or animals to explain or teach yourself inheritance, it leads to bad ideas and designs. This being said, one of the most important things in OOP is the contract. If your design makes the implementation diverges from the contract, it's probably bad.

Comment: @dystroy Yes, but sometimes you still want/need to do that. Just take IdentityHashMap, for example, which is very useful in some situations because it violates the general contract that Map should use equals and hashCode.

Comment: @kutschkem [This class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/IdentityHashMap.html) is one of the few ones in the standard package coming with a big warning. I'd say this confirms my point.

Comment: Why the downvotes? If you downvote, add a comment at least as this is a good, altough probably a duplicate, question.

Comment: @kutschkem It's probably a bad idea to use Java collections as an example, other than as an example of a mess.

Comment: "How can we implement this?" Any way you want. But you should not do so.

Comment: @dystroy I disagree. It teaches better program design. The animal kingdom example demonstrates how broken inheritance is as a method of code reuse. I think by recognizing that you can start to see how to more effectively design programs using aggregation techniques.

Comment: A very relevant objective discussion could have taken place - should not have been closed. Just because there are several answers and some may be opinionated does not mean the question is primarily opinion-based. This is a technical question about measurable program design.

Comment: I agree, this is a fair question about misconception about OOP and existing answers provide good feedback. Should be reopened.

Answer (score 6):

The Mammal class should only define common characteristics to all mammals, as you said walking is not a common feature.

Behaviour could be added by using interfaces, like in the following example

```
class abstract Mammal {

    abstract void regulateTemperature();

}

interface CanFly {

    void land();
    void takeOff();

}

class Bat extends Mammal implements CanFly {

}
```

Sorry if I've made syntax errors, my Java is a bit rusty, but you got the idea, just be as generic as you can in your base class. That said I agree with @dystroy, it's way too difficult to get inheritance right with the animal domain. You might want to try by modelling a lamp, or a shirt, start with something way more simple than this.

Answer (score 2):

Your assertions contradict each other.

- Like there is Mammal class have behavior of walking which all subclasses should adhere to.
- But there are few mammals like Dolphin and Bat which does not have this behavior possessed.

Either all subclasses have the behavior, or not all have the behavior. You can't have both.

In object-oriented design, it is useful for all subclasses to support the contracts of their superclass, so that an instance of any subclass can be used anywhere that a superclass is referenced. This is known as the [Liskov substitution principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle).

Comment: I was just about link to the Liskov principle, but I guess someone beat me to it!

Answer (score 2):

You have just discovered the fundamental problem with the concept of traditional inheritance and OOP. Classifying objects into strict categories is extremely difficult in even the most trivial examples (interestingly, classification is a big part of IQ tests). When studying the example of the animal kingdom it quickly becomes apparent that grouping times into strict, top down, subdividing, categories doesn't make sense. Combine this idea with programming and trying to reuse functionality and you may end up killing yourself.

Modern OOP avoids using inheritance for code reuse and instead exploits it for polymorphism. Deep inheritance trees are fragile and considered bad practice. Code reuse is instead accomplished through aggregation. Small objects and their behaviors are mixed and matched to create much more complex objects. This behavior is enhanced using concepts like dependency injection and policy based design.

For more info, and practical applications of these concepts, read:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aspect-oriented_programming

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Component-based_software_engineering

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Policy-based_design

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection

Answer (score 0):

Simple, use a `Walking` interface that you can use for animals that walk.

For example:

```
interface Walking {
    public abstract void walk();  // implementing classes must implement this
}

class Cow extends Mammal implements Walking {
    public void walk() { ... }
}

class Dolphin extends Mammal {
    public void swim() { ... }
}

class Bat extends Mammal {
    public void fly() { ... }
}
```

Comment: Bats and dolphins are mammals.

Answer (score 0):

The Mammal class is not defined correctly in your example since not all mammals can walk. It shouldn't include a `walk` method. I would opt for a Walking interface instead in that case, with Swimming and Flying interfaces also for the other methods used to move.

Answer (score 0):

If you define Mammal as having a Walk() method, then you're saying that all mammals can walk.

Your implementation for Dolphin might look like this:

```
public void Walk()
{
    throw new TraitLossException();
}
```

http://www.nescent.org/science/awards_summary.php?id=24

Comment: Please don't do this.. violates liskovs substitution principle. Your class advertises that adheres to a contract and than throws an exception arbitrarily.

Comment: Hi @JustinMeiners, I appreciate in purist terms this isn't a good idea, but sometime software becomes quite complex and starts evolving (much life species!), so inevitably you end up throwing the odd NotSupportedException from time to time. These things are definitely technical debt, and I would try and avoid doing this in a greenfield project, but sometimes it is expedient to repurpose a class for something it wasn't originally designed for, much like a mammal learning to swim!

Comment: I absolutely agree that when using inheritance code reuse in a real project it is an inevitability. When inheritance is used as a tool for polymorphism and not code reuse I think it is reasonable to accomplish this goal.

Answer (score 0):

Disclaimer: this answer is not about good design, but about existing practice.

Sometimes, you have a subclass that can't (or just won't) provide all the services the superclass offers. One prominent example would be Iterator.remove(), which can or can not be implemented. When such a situation appears in the Standard libraries, a UnsupportedOperationException is generally thrown. In some cases, like Iterator, it is in a sense even part of the contract that an implementation that does not support the operation should throw the exception.

Comment: If this is about existing library specifics, why are we designing theoretical animals?

Comment: @JustinMeiners I don't know, i thought the animals are only an example. Are we really interested in Animal modeling here? If it's really about animal modeling, i'd rather use any AOP language like scala than using java...

Answer (score 0):

This is one of those cases where it may makes sense to subclass a non-abstract class.

```
class Mammal {
    ...
    /** May not walk. This implementation succeeds. */
    void walk() {
        ... do some walking ...
    }
}

class WateronlyMammal extends Mammal {
    @Override void walk() {
        ... sit there looking sad ...
    }
}
```

Then create types of animals as `new Mammal("Dog")` or `new WateronlyMammal("Dolphin")`.

Alternative you may want composition instead of inheritance, which trades verbosity for simpler components.

```
 interface Walker {
     /** May not walk. */
     void walk();
 }
 final class Mammal {
     public Mammal(String speciesName, Walker walk) {
         ...
     }
     ...
 }
```

Creating as `new Mammal("Dog", competentWalker())` or `new Mammal("Dolphin", notSoGoodWalker())`.

May even add convenience constructors:

```
     public Mammal(String speciesName) {
         this(speciesName, competentWalker(), poorFlyer());
     }
```

(Note we've got some confusion here with type of species and a particular animal being. Also worth noting if you take every animal that ever existed, there are no species boundaries.)